# MySQL. Default length for a field

Tags: mysql, database-design, datatypes

Is there a list of already set standards for some common fields like: firstName, lastName, email, phone?

I see most people just set varchar(300) to all fields, does it affect performance in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggested max len**

First, I will mention some common strings that are always hex, or otherwise limited to ASCII.  For these, you should specify `CHARACTER SET ascii` (`latin1` is ok) so that it will not waste space:

```
UUID CHAR(36) CHARACTER SET ascii -- or pack into BINARY(16)
country_code CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET ascii
ip_address CHAR(39) CHARACTER SET ascii -- or pack into BINARY(16)
phone VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ascii -- probably enough to handle extension
postal_code VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET ascii -- (not 'zip_code') (don't know the max

city VARCHAR(100) -- This Russian town needs 91:
    Poselok Uchebnogo Khozyaystva Srednego Professionalno-Tekhnicheskoye Uchilishche Nomer Odin
country VARCHAR(50) -- probably enough
name VARCHAR(64) -- probably adequate; more than some government agencies allow
```

**Why not simply 255?**
There are two reasons to avoid the common practice of using (255) for everything.

- When a complex `SELECT` needs to create temporary table (for a subquery, `UNION`, `GROUP BY`, etc), the preferred choice is to use the `MEMORY` engine, which puts the data in RAM.  But `VARCHARs` are turned into `CHAR` in the process.  This makes `VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` take 1020 bytes.  That can lead to needing to spill to disk, which is slower.
- In certain situations, InnoDB will look at the potential size of the columns in a table and decide that it will be too big, aborting a `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: Is there a list where I can see how much space takes each character set?

Comment: ascii, latin* - 1 byte per character; utf8 - max of 3; utf8mb4 - max of 4.  "No one" needs the other character sets.  When converting to `CHAR`, the max is used.  (I can't remember where I got the data.)

Comment: thanks. i have published another question. maybe you want to give it a look

Comment: Note:  English text in a `VARCHAR` or `TEXT` that is `CHARACTER SET utf8` will take only 1 byte per char; [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues) has examples of how many bites are needed in utf8 for various languages.